# Is a question about the locomotion of Curiosity (the Mars rover) on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I was going to ask what the primary reason is that Curiosity is so slow... is that on-topic here?

(If not, any ideas if any SE site is suitable for it?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The FAQ states](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/faq#questions)

> Questions related to the maintenance and repair of motor vehicles and
>   their accessories, internal combustion engines, even in applications
>   other than automotive so long as the question is related to engine or
>   engine accessories

The Mars rover has nothing to do with the repair of motor vehicles.

Comment: What if the question starts with “So, I have 2012 Mars Rover, and lately it has been going around really slow.”?

Answer (score 4):

Seen as a question on experimental design this comes pretty close to being suitable for Physics.SE (where I am a moderator).

However, the focus would have to be on how the mission constraints and requirements led to a low speed (and I think the answer may be "because it doesn't need to be fast", frankly).

[Some related questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=rover), which may also supply some tagging suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it's hard to keep up with all the different sites and what they cover.